# Batch copy files from tab delimited file

Tags: powershell, batch-file, copy

I have a tab delimited file with the first column containing the current location of a file, the second column contains where i would like the file to be copied to.

How can i create a script to do this automatically e.g Powershell or Windows Batch?

Many Thanks

Brendan

Answer (score 3):

The following works if your columns in the CSV are named `Path` and `Destination`:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv -Delimiter "`t" | Copy-Item
```

If your columns are named differently (`File` and `TargetPath` here), you need a bit of translation:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv -Delimiter "`t" | ForEach-Object {
  Copy-Item -Path $_.File -Destination $_.TargetPath
}
```

If you have no column headers at all you need to tell `Import-Csv` that:

```
Import-Csv foo.csv -Delim "`t" -Headers Path,Destination | Copy-Item
```

The same in a batch file:

```
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=   " %%A in (foo.csv) do (
  rem                             ↖ that's a tab
  copy "%%~A" "%%~B"
)
```

Comment: would this work if the path included the location too e.g H:\folder\file.doc and target was h:\folder1\

Comment: Yes. If in doubt, read `Get-Help Copy-Item -Param Path` or look at the examples of that cmdlet.

Comment: Admittedly, the first solution is kinda a cop-out since it makes use of the very cool feature of PowerShell that passing data in a pipeline can use parameters by property name. I have rarely used it so far but if your input data looks right it can make for a very short script :)

Comment: This is the error im getting (Multiple times)Copy-Item : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
At line:1 char:35
+ $data | ForEach-Object { Copy-Item <<<<  $_.File $_.TargetPath }
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Copy-Item], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCom
   mand

Comment: Well, adapt to the column names in your CSV.

Comment: I had a problem with the copy command in batch but xcopy worked well - 'code' for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims= "  %%A in (file.csv) do (
  xcopy /h/i/c/k/e/r/y "%%~A" "%%~B"

) @Joey